# Перегрузка оператор С++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, операторы

Такой вопрос. Я перегружаю операторы для работы с вектором, который состоит из трек точек. Есть несколько задач:

- Найти скалярное произведения векторов; (возвращает double)
- Найти векторное произведения векторов; (возвращает вектор)

И получается такая проблема, что компилятор не знает какой из двух методов вызвать (хотя они отличаются возвращающимися параметрами). И как все это решить?

```
using namespace std;
class Vec3D
{
private:
    double x, y, z;
public:
    Vec3D(double xx = 0, double yy = 0, double zz =0);
    Vec3D operator+ (const Vec3D & V);
//  double operator* (const Vec3D & V); // проблема тут
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& cout, Vec3D & V);
    friend Vec3D operator* (const double c, const Vec3D & V);   
    friend Vec3D operator* (const Vec3D & V1,const Vec3D & V2); // и тут
};
```

P.S. То что нужно реализовать семеричные\бинарные операции через friend функции я знаю

Comment: Можно уточнить у вас, как автора вопроса - у нас тут с Vlad from Moscow разногласие - вас интересует скалярное умножение векторов или умножение вектора на скаляр? Просто вот цитата от @Vlad - *Я думаю, что требуется именно скалярное умножение векторов, и умножение векторов на скаляр.*

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы было и векторное умножение, где я получаю в ответе вектор. И скалярное умножение, где я умножаю вектор на вектор и получаю число.

Comment: А что такое "семеричная операция"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Компилятор в общем случае не может определить, какую вызывать перегруженную функцию только по возвращаемому значению. Например, рассмотрите следующий фрагмент кода

```
void f() {}
int f() { return 0; }

f();
```

Как определить, какая функция из двух вызывается?

Поэтому функции не перегружаются по возвращаемому значению.

Перегрузите этот оператор следующим образом, как показано в демонстрационной программе ниже.

```
#include <iostream>

class Vec3D
{
private:
    double x, y, z;

public:
    Vec3D( double x = 0, double y = 0, double z =0) : x( x ), y( y ), z( z )
    {
    }

    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const  Vec3D &v );
    friend Vec3D operator *( const Vec3D &V, double d );   
    friend Vec3D operator *( double d, const Vec3D &v );   
    friend Vec3D operator *( const Vec3D &V1, const Vec3D &V2 ); // и тут
};

std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const  Vec3D &v )
{
    return os << "( " << v.x << ", " << v.y << ", " << v.z << " )";
}

Vec3D operator *( const Vec3D &v, double d )
{
    return Vec3D( d * v.x, d * v.y, d * v.z );
}

Vec3D operator *( double d, const Vec3D &v )
{
    return v * d;
}
Vec3D operator *( const Vec3D &v1, const Vec3D &v2 )
{
    return Vec3D( v1.x * v2.x, v1.y * v2.y, v1.z * v2.z );
}

int main() 
{
    Vec3D v1( 1, 2, 3 );
    Vec3D v2( 1, 2, 3 );

    std::cout << ( 2 * v1 ) * ( v2 * 3 ) << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
( 6, 24, 54 )
```

Нельзя перегрузить оператор по возвращаемому типу. Но вы могли бы взять еще один оператор, как, например, `operator ^`, чтобы использовать его для одного из видов произведения векторов.

В итоге у вас может получиться два оператора

```
operator *
```

и

```
operator ^
```

Объявление перегруженного оператора `operator ^` может выглядеть аналогично объявлению оператора `operator *` за исключением типа возвращаемого значения.

Comment: @batya  Я подправил один оператор *, так как там была опечатка и вместо переменной z использовалась переменная x.

Comment: Или я чего-то не понял, или тут нет ни скалярного, ни векторного умножений векторов...

Comment: @Harry Это все зависит от того, как вы их определите. :) А почему вы решили, что произведения вектора на скаляр здесь нет?

Comment: E автора вопроса речь идет о скалярном и векторном произведении векторов, потому и проблема возникла - что в произведении участвуют два вектора. Скалярное произведение - это не произведение на скаляр: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5  и https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: @Harry Ну, тело операторов модно переписать как угодно. В этом проблемы нет.

Comment: Проблема в том, что сигнатура для скалярного умножения векторов точь-в-точь такая же, как и для векторного умножения. Отличаются они **только** возвращаемым значением. `operator *( const Vec3D &v, double d )` - это умножение вектора на скаляр, а не скалярное умножение векторов.

Comment: @Harry Я думаю, что требуется именно скалярное умножение векторов, и умножение векторов на скаляр. С точки зрения математики скалярное произведение векторов определено неправильно, но эьл личное дело автора, как он его определит.

Comment: По-моему, автор указал проблему предельно четко...

Comment: @Harry Меня ввело в заблуждение слово параметры в его фразе,, что они отличаются возвращаемыми параметрами. Но если автора вопроса устроил мой ответ, то ему виднее.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow. Была проблема в том, что векторное умножение вектора V1 на V2 должно возвращать некий вектор V3. А скалярное умножение V1 на V2 должно возвращать одно число типа double. Я сам разобрался с этой проблемой. И решил просто поставить галочку, что бы вопрос считался закрытым.

Comment: @batya Да, нельзя перегрузить оператор по возвращаемому типу.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow. Я просто реализовал векторное умножение через перегрузку оператора*. А скалярное через отдельный метод. Это единственный способ решение данной проблемы? Или есть другой путь о котором я не знаю?

Comment: @batya Это единственный способ, если использовать один и тот же оператор. Но вы могли бы для одного из произведений выбрать другой оператор, как , например, operator ^.

Comment: @batya Я дополню свой ответ.

Comment: Можно воспользоваться красивым методом, который в своем ответе предложил @Qwertiy - компилятор (VC++) оказался достаточно умным, чтобы не вычислять то, что вычислять не нужно :)

Comment: @Harry На мой взгляд лучше ввести еще один оператор. Дело в том, что в том решении, на которое вы ссылаетесь, возникает проблема с выводом в поток возвращаемого объекта.

Comment: Да, конечно же, это далеко не панацея. Но и у метода подмены операторов есть свои минусы - даже не говоря о семантике оператора `^` (или иного взамен) встает вопрос приоритетов в выражениях типа `A^B*C`. В любом случае слишком много факторов, которые надо учитывать при проектировании, чтобы можно было советовать что-то однозначно :(

Comment: @Harry, а в моём варианте такое вообще не прокатит. Надо будет явно обращаться к свойству: `(a*b).vector * c` :(

Comment: @Qwertiy  Почему же? Вспомним шаблонные выражения :) Надо будет дописать переходник - множить v3d_mr на v3d... В конце-концов, что такое программирование? https://youtu.be/4UhESx6vK4c

Comment: @Harry, а там уже неизвестно, как множить))) Эх.. Как жаль, что это видео без звука...

Comment: `void f() {} int f() { return 0; } f();` По моему здесь все очевидно - `void f()`. Если ф-я имеет перегрузки по возвр. значению, но не определенна перегрузка по типу void тогда такой вызов должен приводить к ошибке, также ошибку компиляции должны вызывать любые неоднозначности вида: `int foo(char x); int foo(long* x); char bar(); long* bar(); ... foo(bar());`, а код `auto x = bar();` и `typeof(bar())` будет допустим только если ф-я bar имеет только две перегрузки по возвр. значению, одна из которых по типу void.

Answer (score 4):

Тут можно постараться и сделать, например, такое (но это не означает, что так делать надо):

http://ideone.com/8wAlaK

```
#include <cstdio>

struct v3d
{
    double x, y, z;
};

struct v3d_mr // multiplication result
{
    double scalar;
    v3d vector;

    operator double () { return this->scalar; }
    operator v3d () { return this->vector; }
};

v3d_mr operator * (const v3d &a, const v3d &b)
{
    return
    {
        a.x*b.x + a.y*b.y + a.z*b.z,
        { a.y*b.z - a.z*b.y, a.z*b.x - a.x*b.z, a.x*b.y - b.x*a.y }
    };
}

int main()
{
    v3d a = {1, 2, 3}, b = {4, 5, 6};

    double s = a * b;
    v3d v = a * b;

    printf("%lf\n", s);
    printf("%lf %lf %lf\n", v.x, v.y, v.z);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Однако!... снимаю шляпу :)

Comment: @Harry, а как думаешь, компилятор это будет оптимизировать, чтобы выкинуть вычисления ненужного поля?

Comment: Честно говоря, не думаю, что он будет настолько умным. Но, так сказать, ни голову, ни иную часть тела не положу :) Но с VC++ повожусь чуть позже.

Comment: Да, VC++2015 оказался достаточно умным, чтоб заинлайнить все вычисления (если оставить ваш код, он просто считал едва ли не все в время компиляции :), так что я добавил считывание векторов через `scanf`), и вычислять только необходимое... Так что признаю - я его недооценил.

Comment: А вообще, смотрю, похоже, пора менять парадигму. Если раньше считалось правильным все упрятывать в библиотеки (.lib), оставляя в заголовках только объявления, то, похоже, сейчас более эффективным способом работы являются библиотеки в исходниках - с ростом скорости и возможностей компиляторов. Основной минус, как я понимаю, будет в том, что как по Петру I - "давать все в исходниках, дабы дурость каждого сразу была видна" :)

Comment: @Harry, круто! А вот про преимущества библиотек в исходниках что-то не понял. Думаешь, они инлайниться будут?

Comment: Думаю, что вызовов реально будет поменьше, оптимизация будет побольше, ну, словом, что эффект будет. Да уже сейчас посмотреть - одна библиотека шаблонов чего стоит :) Недавно, кстати, натолкнулся на то, что, мол, PIMPL использовать не стоит - лишняя косвенность, а перекомпиляция сейчас совсем не та, что 10 лет назад, что идиома PIMPL тогда имела смысл, но не сейчас...

Comment: @Harry, впервые о нём слышу. Прочитал что-то. Странная штука.

Comment: @Qwertiy, так они и из библиотек инлайнятся вполне неплохо. Тут наверное все дело в том что объектный файл подключить проще чем библиотеку, вместо двух параметров с ключами (-l<libname> -L<path>) всего один без ключа (путь к *.o файлу), в крайнем случае можно через #include если с консолью совсем на "Вы"  :-).

Answer (score 2):

Понятие сигнатуры функции не включает возвращаемый тип, поэтому использовать перегрузку для одинаковых типов параметров, но разных возвращаемых типов в C++ нельзя.

Увы, решайте проблему иначе...

P.S. Недаром они даже в математике обозначаются по-разному :)

Comment: Зато можно объединить и скастить :D

Answer (score 1):

Если и говорить про структуры, то давайте про C вспомним с функциональным программированием:

```
typedef struct s_v3d {double x, y, z;} Vector3;
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;

uint32_t vec3d_scalar_mul(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, float* presult) {
    *presult = a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y + a.z * b.z;
    return 0; // errcode
}
uint32_t vec3d_vec_mul(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, Vector3* presult) {
    presult->x = a.y * b.z - a.z * b.y;
    presult->y = a.z * b.x - a.x * b.z;
    presult->z = a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x;
    return 0; //errcode
}
```

А как красиво это потом выглядит:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Vector3 a, b, v;
    a = {1, 2, 3}; // Прямо как массив. Хотя даже не как. Структура и есть массив.
    b = {1, 2, 3};
    double scal;
    vec3d_scalar_mul(a, b, &scal);
    vec3d_vec_mul(a, b, &z);
    printf("scal: %f\tvec: %f, %f, %f\n", scal, v.x, v.y, v.z);
    return 0;
}
```

Мой тебе совет, реализуй оба метода и не парься о выборе возвращаемого значения. Хотя нет, можно вернуть оба значения по желанию...

```
uint32_t vec3d_mul(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, double* pscalres, Vector3* pvecres) {
    if (pscalres == pvecres && pscalres == NULL) return 1; // ERR
    if (pscalres != NULL) {
        *pscalpres = a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y + a.z * b.z;
    }
    if (pvecres != NULL) {
        pvecres->x = a.y * b.z - a.z * b.y;
        pvecres->y = a.z * b.x - a.x * b.z;
        pvecres->z = a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x;
    }
    return 0; // OK
}
```

Comment: правильное решение, **плюсовики** сами себе создают проблемы. Перегрузка операторов была предназначена совсем для другого. И функции, выполняющие **другие** задачи должны называться по-другому. ***float** поменяйте на **double***.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, верно подмечено. Хотя думаю я избыточно выполнил задачу и правильнее написать только функцию для получения скалярного произведения отдельно от перегруженного оператора.

P. S. Знаешь, что смешно? То, что на сях у тебя есть очевидный способ решения проблемы, но как только включаешь в дело ооп из плюсов, как начинаются проблемы...