# Поменять тип возвращаемого значения функции

Tags: c++, c, макросы, макрос, macro

Можно ли как-то у функции с известным названием с помощью макроса поменять тип возвращаемого значения?

Comment: @Abyx была функция `int foo()` в файле 1, а в файл 2 включить файл 1 только с макросом, который заменит `inf foo()` на `void foo()`

Comment: @Abyx я не компилирую 1 и 2 вместе. Это 2 разные функции будут

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/621177/178988 - похоже?

Comment: @Qwertiy да, что-то подобное у меня происходит

Comment: @степан, ну так так и делай?

Comment: Почему с помощью макроса? Это очень смахивает на проблему XY. Что вы вообще пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: @VTT сомневаюсь, что это можно сделать по-другому

Comment: Что сделать-то?

Comment: @VTT заменить функцию на другую функцию с другим возвращаемым значением. Именно заменить, а не объявить новую

Comment: И зачем такое могло понадобится? Приведите конкретный пример, в котором могла возникнуть такая необходимость. А то пока впечатление, что вы собираетесь забивать гвозди микроскопом.

Comment: @VTT ну там большой контекст. Мне интересно именно то, как сделать то, что в вопросе, а не как по-другому решить задачу верхнего уровня

Comment: Как и в других вопросах по проблеме XY, то, что в вопросе, с 80% вероятностью окажется бессмысленным в контексте решения настоящей задачи.

Comment: Вы можете менять само объявление функции? Если да, то можно засунуть возвращаемый тип в `#ifdef`...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat к сожалению, не могу

Comment: @степан, я правильно понял, что у вас есть `file1.h` с описанием прототипа функции `int foo()`, который инклюдится в `file2.cpp`, но из него вы хотите вызывать `void foo()`? Если да, то есть ли у вас возможность редактировать `file1.h`?

Comment: А вообще, перегрузка функций изначально дурацкая (к сожалению, повсеместно укоренившаяся) идея. Попробуйте сами себе честно ответить на вопрос, зачем вам в вашей задаче называть 2 разные функции одним и тем же именем? Лень?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Можно с помощью макросов, а можно по современнее, используя пространство имён.

main.hpp:

```
namespace A {
 static inline  int f(void){return 0;}
}

namespace B {
 static inline void f(void){ A::f(); } 
}
```

file1.cpp :

```
# include "main.hpp"
using A::f;
int i = f();
```

file2.cpp :

```
# include "main.hpp"
using B::f;
f();
```

В разных файлах будет использоваться по-умолчанию предлагаемая реализация функции **f**;

А вот так с макросами:

main.hpp:

```
static inline int A_f(void){return 0;}

static inline void B_f(void){ A_f(); }
```

file1.cpp :

```
# include "main.hpp"
# define f A_f
int i = f();
```

file2.cpp :

```
# include "main.hpp"
# define f B_f
f();
```

Comment: Занятно, что этот ответ был принят, хотя ничего похожего на *"поменять тип возвращаемого значения"* тут не происходит, а часть с макросом аналогична другому ответу, который ОПу отчего-то не понравился.

Comment: @VTT, подозреваю что фишка второй части ответа (а впрочем и первой) в добавлении inline - они же в объектный файл не попадают? Или всё равно попадают?

Comment: @Qwertiy Они обе будут попадать, но если какая-то не используется, то компилятор ее выкинет. С другой стороны, добавление `static` могло бы позволить избежать проблем с ODR, если бы тип возвращаемого значения заменялся.

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/qz2F6s

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char f() { return ' '; }
char g() { return ' '; }

int main()
{
  #define f(...) ((int)f(__VA_ARGS__))

  cout << '[' << f() << ']' << endl;
  cout << '[' << g() << ']' << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

```
[32]
[ ]
```

Comment: а этот дефайн можно ведь вне функции `main` написать?

Comment: @степан, в любом месте можно. Только после самой функции и её прототипа. Причём в файле, где она будет использоваться, либо в заголовочном, чтобы define в использование попал.

Comment: А это точно именно заменяет функцию `f`, а не объявляет новую? То есть после дефайна никак нельзя обратиться к старой `f`?

Comment: для этого есть #undef

Comment: @степан, это ничего не заменяет, прочитай, что вообще делает define. Обратиться к старой можно только после `#undef` или из кода до `#define`.

Comment: @Qwertiy как это не заменяет? я думал, что это буквально замена одного текста на другой, только после этого компиляция... В объектный файл у нас попадёт одна функция `f` или две?

Comment: Не, я протестировал. Не заменяет, а добавляет новую функцию. А мне надо именно замена, т.е. дефайн должен быть перед функцией

Comment: @степан, define никогда никаких функций не добавляет. Иди уже теорию читать.

Comment: @Qwertiy я почитал, но в объектный файл попадает именно `char f()`, а не `int f()`, как бы я хотел

Answer (score 1):

Для таких целей не нужно пытаться использовать макроопределения. Я бы просто вернул из функции тип,  который может преобразоваться и в тот и в другой тип. Пока не понятна ваша цель, поэтому приведу простенький пример.

```
class Ret {
    char c;
public:
    Ret(const char ch) : c(ch){}
    operator int() { return c; }
    operator char() { return std::toupper(c); }
};
Ret foo() { 
    return Ret('a');
}
```

Так как `Ret`  может преобразоваться и в `char` и в `int`, можем написать следующую программу:

```
char a = foo();
int k = foo();
std::cout << a << '\n' << k;
```

Но  в некоторых случаях такой тип может быть источником неодназначности(потому я и указал, что не понятна ваша цель). Здесь может помочь наследование, шаблоны или же определение другого типа...

Comment: О, я тут вспомнил: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/586066/178988 :)