# Перегрузка методов класса по типу возвращаемого значения

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода

Требуется реализовать перегрузку методов класса по типу возвращаемого значения, у меня пока есть такое решение, может кто-то подсказать что-то лучше?

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##rVTbboJAEH3nKyY2acCocaHtA25J1F/wndB1bUm4BRajMX67nV1YLhZD2tQHM86emXPmJsuy@Sdjt9tTmLCo3HOgYVqInAexZxgsCooC1nAxAD9Z@RGFzFW24HEWBYJTcc54EsQcdp562MHBtFbKHAOmGc8Dkeam9duIqcnSpBCwfoYjhl5XhtFEeRAm@OK6qAMukHNR5gmQFVy7mH2KxfAfMHuxlMCBbF2xLd55mHYY/zKav1daG/g6SvQg8K1mxJmWTMCG1MPcEHM9lUgXjr4pI64Pu9/0HXbdYo7@3DvQnYfTgypYZvRxlHIgmtDWhPa/ELZ9HWV2NLOjmMkM2g7ZSgdBIcSa4U807D9JIh1NUykJc/VUEb/a7Q63Flqd1xaVVKc1eGk4sd6K4uDEV1g0HNjg4V3DhveBDozsCjZKRszkUWGQlCi3Mw7CxLSMStoWWFWPfDkReAe2aC6@3srznVtBbem7B/acCuZID0w1iwbeudVXIfauy9JSUHoilE5gQulZGydbe7RxcrQHDRXLk32ENcpcdQeW@Gdyu30D)

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
    template<typename T>
    T f();
    
    template<typename T>
    T operator()();
    
    template<typename T>
    T operator*(const A& v);
};

template<> int A::f() { return 1; }
template<> double A::f() { return 2.0; }

template<> int A::operator()() { return 3; }
template<> double A::operator()() { return 4.0; }

template<> int A::operator*(const A& v) { return 5; }
template<> double A::operator*(const A& v) { return 6.0; }

struct B1 {
    B1(A* v) : v_(v) {}
    template<typename T> operator T() { return v_->f<T>(); }
    A* v_;
 };

struct B2 {
    B2(A* v) : v_(v) {}
    template<typename T> operator T() { return v_->operator()<T>(); }
    A* v_;
 };

struct B3 {
    B3(A* v1, const A& v2) : v1_(v1), v2_(v2) {}
    template<typename T> operator T() { return v1_->operator*<T>(v2_); }
    A* v1_;
    const A& v2_;
 };

class C : public A {
    public:
    B1 f() { return B1(this); }
    B2 operator()() { return B2(this); }
    B3 operator*(const A& v) { return B3(this, v); }
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    int x1 = c.f();
    double y1 = c.f();
    int x2 = c();
    double y2 = c();
    int x3 = c * c;
    double y3 = c * c;
    
    std::cout<<x1<<" "<<y1<<" "<<x2<<" "<<y2<<" "<<x3<<" "<<y3<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/586051/178988

Comment: @
Максим
, вроде красиво получилось. Что конкретно хочется улучшить?

Comment: @Qwertiy, хотелось бы понять, насколько корректен код, предполагалось использование в классе чтения параметров конфигурационного файла, сейчас эта функциональность реализована через перегрузку по типу аргумента, в качестве которого передаётся ссылка и в неё записывается значение, но это не очень удобно.