# Проблема в возврате значений operator[]

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Проблема в возврате значений, проблема это -
**string& operator[] (const string index) и bool& operator[] (const string index)** и она мне не позволяет взять значение с string(возвращает 1) но когда я переставляю строки местами(bool& на string&,вместе с их содержимым) то всё получается наоборот и возвращает пустоту, как это можно исправить?
Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class StringData
{
private:
    map<string, string> dataStrings;
    map<string, bool> dataBools;
public:
    string& operator[] (const string index)
    {
        return dataStrings[index];
    }
    bool& operator[] (const string index)
    {
        return dataBools[index];
    }
};

int main() 
{
    StringData a;
    a["test"] = false;
    a["test2"] = "Hello";
    cout << a["test"];
    cout << a["test2"];
    system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: Ничего не напутали? У меня ваш код [не собирается вообще](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/oGxnEvv1T).

Comment: В таком виде, как вы написали, это не получится заставить работать. Вам нужна одна мапа, хранящая [`std::variant<std::string, bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Comment: А как это вы хотите два оператора от одного и того же типа? Вы явно хотите странного...

Comment: variant<string, bool>& operator[] (const string index) // error не является шаблоном
 {
  return dataStrings[index];
 }
Так должно выглядеть?

Comment: В таком виде, как вы написали, это не получится заставить работать. Вам нужна одна мапа, хранящая std::variant<std::string, bool>. – HolyBlackCat , такой вариант не подоходит(

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ну теоретически, функции, определённые прямо в классе - это inline, а валидировать их на то, что все реализации одинаковы, компилятор не должен. Хотя, тут же явная перегрузка по возвращаемому значению... Но может компилятор может в каких-то условиях проворонить и выбрать первую?

Comment: @Qwertiy То, что вы говорите, это когда в каждом TU (единице трансляции) функция одна, но в разных TU у нее разные тела. А тут две функции в одном TU. Компилятор (по крайней мере мой) не успеет проворонить, потому что выдает ошибку сразу как видит вторую функцию.

Comment: @artEA *"такой вариант не подоходит"* Если есть какие-то скрытые ограничения, то расскажите о них. Мы же не можем угадывать.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, не подходить может в том случае, если значения не взаимоисключающие.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вариант от @Harry весьма странный и на код ревью я бы жестоко отказал за такое. Возьмём предложение @HolyBlackCat и оформим

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <variant>

using namespace std;

class StringData
{
public:
    // будем храть все в варианте, но это с++17
    using two_t = std::variant<string,bool>;
private:
    map<string, two_t> dataStrings;
public:
    two_t& operator[] (const string index)
    {
        return dataStrings[index];
    }
};
// нам нужен оператор вывода этой структуры
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const StringData::two_t& t) {
    if(auto pval = std::get_if<std::string>(&t)) {
      os << *pval;
    }
    else if (auto pval = std::get_if<bool>(&t)) {
      os << *pval;
    }
    else {
        os << "<none>"; // ну мало чего
    }
     
    return os;
}

int main() 
{
    StringData a;
    a["test"] = false;
    a["test2"] = "Hello";
    cout << a["test"];
    cout << a["test2"];
}
```

правда оно только для с++17 и старше, но всегда можно и это обойти.

Comment: У меня был интересный вариант, но @Harry его, похоже, уже забыл: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/586066/178988. Хотя, он не совсем подходит к этому вопросу.

Comment: да, хороший вариант. Правда мне нужно туда будет чуточку кода добавить, для стабильности и устойчивости

Comment: Обойти с помощью чего? мне бы желательно всё на с++14

Comment: можно boost variant использовать. А можно написать свою реализацию с struct/union и пару строк обвязки.  Но тут паралельно возник вопрос - а как класс должен реагировать на одинаковые ключи и разные типы?

Comment: А можно написать свою реализацию с struct/union и пару строк обвязки.  KoVadim, можно по подробнее?

Comment: дайте ответ на вопрос о одинаковых типах

Comment: дайте ответ на вопрос о одинаковых типах – KoVadim, думаю перезаписывать на этот тип который присваивается

Comment: я написал у себя вариант без variant, на union, но оно такое большое и страшное получилось... надо подумать, может как то сократить можно.

Comment: @KoVadim посмотреть можно?

Comment: вот так, но получилось, что variant ручками написан... мне оно не очень нравится https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dqb8Gdj3q

Comment: Да, ваш вариант рабочий, код бы сократить до читаемости а то мало что понятно и разбираться долговато а так работает)

Comment: так это минимум. Там две составляющие - реализация костыльного "варианта" и определение операторов сравнения - их в принципе можно удалить, я брал с другого примера

Comment: @KoVadim, если вас не затруднит смогли бы вы добавить-изменить этот ответ с использованием variant и без него думаю людям с этой же проблемой будет полезно.

Answer (score 0):

Неработоспособна сама идея - перегрузка, дающая две функции с одинаковыми сигнатурами:

```
string& operator[] (const string index);
bool&   operator[] (const string index);
```

Не допускает такого С++.

Рекомендую решение:

```
class StringData
{
private:
    map<string, string> dataStrings;
    map<string, bool> dataBools;
public:
    string& operator[] (const string index)
    {
        return dataStrings[index];
    }
    bool& operator[] (const char * index)
    {
        return dataBools[index];
    }
};

int main() 
{
    StringData a;
    a["test"] = false;
    a["test2"s] = "Hello";
    cout << a["test"] << endl;
    cout << a["test2"s] << endl;
}
```

Comment: жаль нет метки "не совсем является ответом"

Comment: после исправление совсем полный ужас....

Comment: @KoVadim Ужас будет при использовании `variant`. Но до такого я не опущусь :) Да, знаете результат ваших вечных подначек? Если раньше я относился к вашим комментариям со вниманием, то теперь все больше с "а, это KoVadim, опять какую-то [censored] пишет..." :) Все хорошо в меру.

Comment: Почему же будет? с ним вполне разумно выходит. И я не использую мат или нецензурную/обсценную лексику, так что не нужно:)

Comment: @Harry, а чем тебе variant не угодил?

Comment: @Qwertiy У каждого свой вкус. Предпочитаю простоту. В поставленной задаче я бы вообще использовал `getBool()` и `getString()`, причем отдельно `get` и отдельно `set`. Экономить, с моей точки зрения, на буквах, чтоб код был покороче и понепонятнее, не нужно. А вообще, надо бы посмотреть на сам проект - *для чего* такое решение? Одинаков ли набор строк-ключей или нет? или "почти одинаков"? Плясать надо от задачи, а не от "а я вот такое вот знаю!"...